# how to set Elastica suggest from specific type?

Tags: autosuggest, elastica

I am faily new to elasticsearch and try to get along with elastica. I try to set suggester which suggest from a specific type. I have tried to used a method addType from \Elastica\Search, but it cann't work.

```
$search = new \Elastica\Search($elasticaClient);
$suggest = new \Elastica\Suggest\Term();
$suggest->addTerm('suggest', ['text' => $query, 'term' => ['field' => '_all']]);
$search->addIndex($elasticaIndex);
$search->addType($type);
$search->addSuggest($suggest);
$result = $search->search();
```

may can someone help me to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a search with a type:

```
$elasticaClient = new \Elastica\Client(array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '9200',
));
$type = $elasticaClient->getIndex('index_name')->getType('type_name');

$query = 'Text to be searched';

$suggest = new \Elastica\Suggest();
$term = new \Elastica\Suggest\Term('suggest', '_all');
$term->setText($query);
$suggest->addSuggestion($term);

$result = $type->search($suggest);
```

For more information you can take a look at http://elastica.io/migration/0.90.7/suggest.html